# Nystagmus drug FDA approval?

Tags: human-eye

Congenital [Nystagmus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nystagmus) is an eye focusing disorder. It happens in manuals. Wikipedia lists several treatments on its page. Are any of those FDA approved for human use of that disease.

> drugs found to be effective against nystagmus in some patients include memantine, levetiracetam, 3,4-diaminopyridine, 4-aminopyridine, and acetazolamide.
>   -[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nystagmus)

Comment: googling for the drug name will tell you if it's available. Based on my 4 seconds of research, the first two are.

Comment: @MattDMo no sir i think you're mistaken. would you share your keywords so that i can examine the results and validate that nystagmus is an approved condition of treatment.

Comment: the links i found said otherwise: Curbside Consultation in Neuro-ophthalmology: 49 Clinical Questions

Comment: The mainstay of therapy is pharmacologic and several good options exist for [acquired pendular nystagmus] treatment. Gabapentin has a very tolerable side effect profile a large dosing range and its beneficial effects in suppressing oscillopsia and dampening the nystagmus waveform in APN have been demonstrated in a double-blind controlled trial. (non FDA approved use)

Comment: "Available" is different from "FDA approved for this use." Memantine (Namenda) and Levetiracetam (Keppra) as well as gabapentin (Neurontin) are most certainly *available* to be prescribed for whatever by any doctor, but I doubt any of them is approved for nystagmus. (I don't know for sure, just pointing out this discrepancy in usage.)